# Two touching circles inscribed in an angle

Tags: geometry, congruences-geometry

There are two touching circles inscribed in a $60^\circ$ angle. The distance between the vertex of the angle and the center of the smaller circle is $5j$. What is the ratio of the surfaces of the two circles?

Comment: What do you mean by 5j?

Comment: that is the distance from vertex to the center of the smaller circle

Comment: No, 5 *j*? Is it an unit? Or just a variable?

Comment: I don't know... I wrote the problem exactly as it goes. I suppose as a unit because it has no meaning in the context of this problem. What do you think?

Comment: Where did you get the problem from?

Comment: From a Czech math textbook, "Matematika, prijimaci zkouzky na cvut"

Comment: @slimDeviant When you ask for the ratio of the two circles, do you mean the ratio of their radii? Areas? Regardless, the information in the problem statement specifying the distance between the vertex and the smaller circle's center is superfluous, as the circle ratio is always the same no matter what distance.

Comment: The ration of their surfaces is wanted, i made the appropriate correction up in the question.

Comment: There is [a PDF of this book](http://www.civ.cvut.cz/info/run1.php?did=518). This appears to be problem 21 from page 140. By “surfaces” I guess you mean areas. I take it that both the circles touch both the legs of the angle; otherwise the question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius of the large circle is three times that of the small circle. This is easy to see if you draw things on a triangular grid:

[image: Construction]

Since area scales with the square of the radius, you get an area ratio of $9$. The scale of things, in particular that distance $AD$, is irrelevant for this computation.

Comment: Your answer about the ratio is correct, the ratio is indeed 9, but something else is worying me... 
Is there a slight chance that this relationship could be derived from the data that I've given, more precisely from the distance of vertex of the angle to the center of the smaller circle?

Since your answer is correct and since it matches with the answer given in this book, do you care to explain your reasoning for this soluton, to show me how you got there, preferably without the use of the grid?

Comment: @slimDeviant: I got there by doing the construction in Cinderella. But you *could* get there e.g. by computing coordinates. If you choose them well enough, the solution will be as simple as the one with the grid. If not, you'll have square roots all over the place. One key element in my construction is that I constructed $FG$ parallel to $EB$, the rest should be clear from the drawing.

Comment: @slimDeviant: You could also start with the fact that $ABD$ is half of an equilateral triangle, so $AD=2\,BD$. With $DB=DE=DF$ you get $AF=3\,AE$. The rest follows by similarity.

Comment: It's maybe rude, but could you please show me the similarity because I'm not able to see?

Comment: @slimDeviant: The similarity transformation characterized by $$A\mapsto A, B\mapsto G, D\mapsto H, C\mapsto K, E\mapsto F$$ is a [homothety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation) with center $A$ and scale factor $\frac{AF}{AE}=3$. It maps the small circle onto the large one.

Comment: Thank you very much, enjoy the rest of the day!